# Using DateTime::CreateFromFormat to create a date object

Tags: php, datetime

I have a string of a date:

```
25/08/2012
```

And here I'm trying to convert it to a DateTime object in order to save it to the MySQL database. My backend schema has a `DateOfPrint date` column ready to receive this data.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $fecha->innertext);
echo $eventDate;
```

The `echo` statement doesn't show anything on the screen, and when trying to save it to the database, nothing is saved in that column.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `$eventDate` contains a boolean(false) which is printed as empty string.

You need to use an upper-case Y.

> Y   A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits    Examples: 1999 or 2003
> y   A two digit representation of a year    Examples: 99 or 03

And you have to call [DateTime::format()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php);
e.g.

```
<?php
$fecha = new StdClass;
$fecha->innertext = '25/08/2012';

$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha->innertext);
if ( false===$eventDate ) {
  die('invalid date format');
}
echo $eventDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

prints

```
2012-08-25
```

Comment: Your answer says I should use format() but your example is using createFromFormat() Which one should I use?

Comment: @Serg - You use `createFromFormat()` to get a `DateTime` object, and `format()` to correctly format that date object to a string that is acceptable for a MySQL `DATE` column.

Comment: Both. createFromFormat() for parsing the string into a datetime objec. And format() to get a (different) string representation back from that object.

Answer (score 3):

You need to format it for a MySQL column before you can insert it:

```
// Need upper case Y here, thanks to VolkerK for pointing that out
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha->innertext);
$eventDate = $eventDate->format( 'Y-m-d'); // I think this is the correct format
```

Then you can use `$eventDate` to save the date to the database.

Comment: I love your work with this class. You get my *40th* +1 for today!

Comment: @Fluffeh - Hah, thanks. It's really a great hidden gem that many don't know about, and it's so useful!

Answer (score 1):

`$eventDate` is an object, not a string. You will need to access the properties of the element in your code to be able to correctly insert it's value into a table or echo it out. On that note, you *could* use a `var_dump($eventDate);` which should show you all there is to know about the object.

You can reference the [PHP docsm on the DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) to get the available properties and see which one best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha->innertext);
echo $eventDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

short answer

```
$st_time =  date('Y-m-d H:i',$yourdate);
```

if you want only day month and year use this

```
$st_time =  date('Y-m-d',$yourdate);
```

Comment: Although your example might work, the OP is specifically asking with regard to the [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)